# Are there any quicker ways to simplify this bevel I have on the bottom of this bottle?

Tags: modeling, mesh, bevel

So far I've been using the *Collapse Edges & Faces* feature to collapse each bit one by one, but I was curious if there's a faster way to simplify this bevel so the mesh looks better. I'm definitely still learning, so I want to learn the right way first.

[image]

Comment: Hi :). It might be easier to delete the whole edge, and bevel it again cleanly :).

Comment: How would I go about doing that? Is there a setting I missed that automatically cleans this up?

Comment: @CheckmateChris1 I added another possible solution as described by Jachym Michal

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @**Jachym Michal** mentioned you can also just delete the whole edge.

1.) Press <kbd>3</kbd> to switch to *Face Select* mode
2.) Click <kbd>LMB</kbd> the bottom face of the bottle
3.) Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Numpad +</kbd> repeatedly until whole edge is selected
4.) Press <kbd>x</kbd> *> Delete Faces*
5.) Press <kbd>2</kbd> to switch to *Edge Select* mode
6.) Click edge <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> to select the edge loop
7.) Press <kbd>F</kbd> to fill in a face to close the bottom
8.) Press <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> and move down along z-axis
9.) Bevel with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd> and move mouse up then scroll middle button upwards to add segments
10.) Click <kbd>LMB</kbd> and you're done

[image]

Answer (score 7):

In *Edit Mode*, press <kbd>1</kbd> to switch to *Vertex Select* mode and select the vertex pairs as shown below then press <kbd>J</kbd> to cut through the mesh & join each pair.

[image]

Then press <kbd>2</kbd> to switch to *Edge Select* mode. Select all edges as shown below and press <kbd>X</kbd> *> Dissolve Edges*

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. In the future please try to avoid text typed inside images. It can't be indexed and as such wont appear in searches, it is harder to read or translate, and can't be easily edited in case of errors, or if things change in the future. Whenever possible prefer text in the body of the question instead, arrows and annotations are fine.

Comment: hmmm but I have written everything as text as well. the text in the images is just added/duplicated aid.

Comment: Indeed, that is better than no text at all. Nitpicking I know, but the best is to avoid text at all inside images.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response with images too! I'm not sure it's quite quicker, but it is a different way to look at it.